# Can thinking too much lead to brain damage?

Tags: brain

I would like to become a mathematician, but am scared by the fact that for instance, Leonhard Euler developed what seems to be called a "cerebral hemorrhage", and he was perhaps the most prolific thinker of mathematics. Now I would like to know: If I use my brain too much, will it suffer from similar stuff, for instance, because there is too much blood flow in the blood vessels of the skull?

Comment: No, highly educated people are less likely to develop Alzheimer's. Your brain can't wear out, like a CPU can't wear out. It has no moving parts, unlike a motor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No

> A cerebral hemorrhage (also spelled haemorrhage) is a type of
> intracranial hemorrhage that occurs within the brain tissue. It can be
> caused by brain trauma, or it can occur spontaneously in hemorrhagic
> stroke. Non-traumatic intracerebral hemorrhage (or hemorrhagic stroke)
> is a spontaneous bleeding into the brain tissue because of rupture of
> blood vessels that may be caused by high blood pressure, amyloidosis (Amyloidosis is a rare, serious disease caused by accumulation of proteins in the form of abnormal, insoluble fibres),
> or structural weakness of blood vessel walls (aneurysms,
> arterio-venous malformations).
>
> *Hemphill, J. Claude; Greenberg, Steven M.; Anderson, Craig S.; Becker, Kyra; Bendok, Bernard R.; Cushman, Mary; Fung, Gordon L.;
> Goldstein, Joshua N.; Macdonald, R. Loch (2015-07-01). "Guidelines for
> the Management of Spontaneous Intracerebral Hemorrhage A Guideline for
> Healthcare Professionals From the American Heart Association/American
> Stroke Association". Stroke. 46 (7): 2032–2060.*